# Flutter Chopper: allow self-signed-certificate for use?

Tags: flutter

I have a spring-boot backend and I run it with HTTPS using a self-signed-certificate.

How to setup the chopper to accept the given certificate?

Answer (score 0):

like that

set before `runApp(app)`;

```
HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
```

class `HttpOverrides`

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
      @override
      HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
        return super.createHttpClient(context)
          ..badCertificateCallback =
              (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: And does the chopper uses this HttpClient?

Comment: @stacktrace2234 
It will support all
DIO, Retrofit, chopper

Comment: And if I don't want to let any certificate through, only that one I have in my assets folder?

Comment: @stacktrace2234

return super.createHttpClient(context)
          ..badCertificateCallback =
              (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => (cert==myCert && host == myHost && port == myPort );

Comment: @stacktrace2234
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/raw/certificate.crt');
SecurityContext context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
client = HttpClient(context: context);